# How can I generate predictions from the randomSurvivalForest package in R?

Tags: r, time-series, survival, predictive-models

I'm trying to use the `randomSurvivalForest` package in `R` to predict the next event in a series of events (using `res <- predict(fit,v)`), but all I get is a total % survivors and then the cumulative hazard for each individual in the `res$ensemble`. Can I use this to predict/generate values matching what's in in `res$time`?

Comment: Or is there some other time series prediction package for repeated events that better to use for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you descibe it with:

> next event in a series of events

It seems like you will definately want to look into time series analysis, perhaps an arima class model can provide you with some good results.